# make webview load only one time in tablayout with lots of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I am using tab-layout with 5 fragment. And each fragment has webview with unique web link. The time I select the tab everything work fine. But when I revisit the same tab which is completed loaded before reloads again.
Is there any why that I can save the content in the fragment so that I have to load fragment link just once.

my code

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        TabLayout tabLayout;
        ViewPager viewPager;
        private int[] tabIcons = {
                R.drawable.ic_tab_1,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_2,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_3,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_4,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_5,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(),"1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "2");
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment3(),"3");
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment4(), "4");
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment5(), "5");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabIcons[4]);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment is

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    WebView web;
    private SmoothProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, viewGroup, false);
        web = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_web);
        mProgressBar = (SmoothProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.google_now);

        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        web.reload();
                    }
                }
        );
        loadingThePage();
        return view;
    }
    private void loadingThePage(){
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
    }


    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            mProgressBar.progressiveStart();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, 
 WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            mProgressBar.progressiveStop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            mProgressBar.progressiveStop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: may be you are looking for this? 
`viewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(5)`

Comment: [May be this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setCacheMode(int))

Comment: @sam_0829 what this does?

Comment: @ApplicationFan this will keep 5 pages in memory. ViewPager only keeps left-right & current page in memory by default. so by this method you are telling it to keep all 5 pages in memory once they are loaded.

Comment: where should i put this? @sam_0829

Comment: in your setupViewPager method, just above this line
`viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);` you should put the one I suggested

Comment: this shows error @sam_0829

Comment: this can't! this is how it should like inside that method
`viewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(5);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: thank you @sam_0829 you save me

Comment: glad it helped, I'll add this as answer so it might help some one also :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
viewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(5);
```

By calling this, you override the default behaviour of `ViewPager` which keeps left-right & current page in memory. Be cautious while using this though. you should not generally keep more pages in memory then the default.

Comment: hi i want to know how to unable uploading of and image in webview website?

Comment: @ApplicationFan unable or enable ?